# Why am I getting "[__NSArrayI allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" / why is NSDictionary transforming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, nsarray, nsdictionary

Looking this `[__NSArrayI allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` error up, it seemingly occurs when you send an NSArray the `allKeys` message which is meant for `NSDictionary`, but in this case I'm very clearly sending it to an NSDictionary.

Here's the code I use when interfacing with the Pocket API:

```
        NSDictionary *articles = [response objectForKey:@"list"];

        // Create an array we can use to sort the keys (and thus the articles) in order of when they were added
        NSMutableArray *allKeys = [[articles allKeys] mutableCopy];
```

The last line there causes the error. But `articles` is very clearly declared as an NSDictionary? Why is it not liking it?

Oddly enough, if I inspect it at runtime it says it's an NSArray! Why did it change?

```
(lldb) po articles
$5 = 0x082103e0 <__NSArrayI 0x82103e0>(

)

(lldb) po [articles class]
$6 = 0x01b83b8c __NSArrayI
(lldb)
```

Comment: It may be a problem with naming your pointer to an NSMutable array `allKeys`. Seeing as this is a method name, it might cause a problem. Also, could you clarify what `[response ...` is.

Comment: response is a JSON response from the Pocket API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be declared in your code as a dictionary, but that doesn't make it a dictionary. It is truly an array and that is why you get the exception. Check your `response` so you know what you should expect.

Your code compiles because the compiler doesn't know that it's going to be an array and it trusts you that it will be a dictionary. It does this because `objectForKey:` returns `id`.

Comment: `po [response class]` outputs `$4 = 0x01b83e34 __NSCFDictionary` though?

Comment: Yes, the response is a dictionary but that doesn't mean that everything it contains is also a dictionary.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Normally `articles` is an `NSDictionary`, when it has many objects from a response, but when it contains none, it seems to be treated as an `NSArray`, right? I just checked, and when a big flux of items comes in, I get this: `(lldb) po [articles class];
$3 = 0x01b83e34 __NSCFDictionary`

Comment: Best to add a check of the type and count then.

Comment: Excellent, a simple check if `articles.count == 0` before I went further fixed it beautifully. Thank you for your knowledge. :)